# how to separate textviews in android?

Tags: android, android-layout, textview

It is a simple question but I don't know how to do it because I'm new in android.

I have two `TextView`s in a relative layout and when the first `TextView` getting bigger it writes on the other `TextView` which I want to avoid it. How can I do it ?

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical">


    <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:text="first"
              android:gravity="left"/>

    <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:text="second"
              android:layout_alignParentRight="true"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

but when the `text = firstfirstfirst....` it overrides the second textview.

Comment: use android:layout_toLeftOf or toRightOf attribute

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to give you `TextViews` ids. Since you're using a `RelativeLayout` you can use `layout_toLeftOf` and `layout_toRightOf`, but you only need to use one of them.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/textView2"
    android:gravity="left"
    android:text="firstfirstfirstfirstfirstfirsitseirodsifjdsoijfoisddsefdfadafdafad" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:text="second" />
```

Comment: yes that is true but then you should add android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" first textview in my stuation. thanks

Comment: but if the right textview is big long, it will make the left textview disappear.

Comment: Yeah, that's right. I updated my answer. You need to add layout weights to keep things spaced evenly.

Answer (score 0):

give some advice:

first you can set the left textview's max width using `android:maxWidth=""` to control the left size, but if the size bigger than the size the text will become like this:`text...`

or you need make the left and right area cleanly, for example:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:weightSum="2" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/left"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:text="firstdasssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssss" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:gravity="left"
    android:text="secondsdasdasdarerewrwcxcadasdasdsadsdasdasdadadsd" />
```

it make the left and right half area, also you can change the `android:weightSum` size.